# How to Correctly use Getter on this Situation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, getter-setter

i've been looking the entire day for a solution to this, but first of all, i want to say im completely new to java and object orientation, so please go easy on me

Then, here is some code i've made so far

Main Class

```html
package br.edu.fatecmm.study;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pessoa ppl = new Pessoa();
        Conta gamer = new Conta();

        gamer.setLogin("kouhei");
        gamer.setPassword("mypass");

        ppl.setNome("Qualquer");
        ppl.setSobrenome("Nome");
        ppl.setJogador(gamer);

        ppl.imprimePessoa();
        gamer.imprimeConta();

    }
}
```

Pessoa Class

```html
package br.edu.fatecmm.study;

public class Pessoa {
    private String nome, sobrenome;
    private Conta jogador;

    public void imprimePessoa(){
        System.out.println("nome = " + nome);
        System.out.println("sobrenome = " + sobrenome);
        System.out.println("jogador = " + jogador.toString());
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public Conta getJogador() {
        return jogador;
    }

    public void setJogador(Conta jogador) {
        this.jogador = jogador;
    }
}
```

Conta Class

```html
package br.edu.fatecmm.study;

public class Conta {
    private String login, password;

    public void imprimeConta(){
        System.out.println("login = " + login);
        System.out.println("password = " + password);
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

So, what happens when i run the code described above is this:

```html
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=49901:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Kouhei\IdeaProjects\Study\out\production\Study br.edu.fatecmm.study.Main
nome = Qualquer
sobrenome = Nome
jogador = br.edu.fatecmm.study.Conta@3498ed
 
login = kouhei
password = mypass
 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Basicaly what i want to do is, when i call
ppl.imprimePessoa();

It should return nome + sobrenome, which is respectively "Qualquer" and "Nome", and then return jogador, which SHOULD be "kouhei" and "mypass", however, instead of kouhei and mypass return, im getting "br.edu.fatecmm.study.Conta@3498ed"

I believe 3498ed is poiting to a memory position, but im not sure, maybe im saying something completely stupid, but i dont even know what to look for to study about this

I tried reading about Getter and Setters, but nothing helps

I also want to be able to retrieve not only "kouhei/mypass" when calling
ppl.imprimePessoa();

But i would also like to be able to retrieve only "kouhei" for example

I tried this

```html
ppl.setJogador(gamer.getLogin());
```

but it doesnt work

I've been trying lots of different methods for hours, and also saw something about instances, however couldnt make it work

Thanks in advance

Comment: "toString" method is inherited from Object, it should be re-defined if you want to change it's output. BTW, Thinking in Java is a good book.

Comment: As @Alex said, jogador is of type Conta, and needs to override the toString method to provide some useful, human readable output. The other variables nome and sobrenome are just of type String, and so output the string literal you initialised or set.

Comment: toString is something i tried "blind", because im so tired of trying stuff and NOTHING works, i just found what im getting is the Memory Location itself, however, not even the Arrays.toString(jogador) works, i dont know what else to do, i need JUST the data itself, not the memory location to finish this stu*** homework :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the default `toString()` what is returned is a string representation of the object.

As explained in java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

If you want to use `toString`, you should override it in class `Conta`, like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "login = " + login + "password = " + password;
}
```

Other possibility if you don't feel comfortable overriding a default method (no problem doing that though, really), is to create a new method that returns a String in class `Conta`. Like:

```
public String jogadorString(){
    return "login = " + login + "password = " + password;
}
```

and use it in class `Pessoa` as `jogador.jogadorString()` instead of `jogador.toString()`.

Comment: after Mr Moose answer, i went to the right direction, but i was still confused about the override thing, however, u clarified everything, many, many thanks dude